NVME RAID Controller performance
I am looking for a RAID controller that allows me to have Hardware RAID 10 on a server.
I have checked "Broadcom MegaRAID 9460-16i" which seems like a good option, but I am concerned that the controller itself might become a performance bottleneck.
If I have 4 NVME disks with a read/write speed of about 4000MB/second, which is not a lot considering some of the U2 disks I see around, how would the controller behave?
Based on their documentation here: https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/BC00-0448EN
I see:

Supports 12, 6, and 3 Gb/s SAS and 6 and 3 Gb/s SATA data transfer rates

12Gb/s means that I can only get 1500MB/sec from the nvme disks? If so, I am losing a lot of performance from the controller.
Alternatives such as these: https://www.highpoint-tech.com/nvme1-gen3/ssd7120
Seem to provide a lot more speed, which would apparently solve the bottleneck, moving the bottleneck back to disk performance.
Am I looking at this the wrong way or reading the data incorrectly? How can a controller advertise itself as being a RAID controller for NVME when in fact it turns an NVME into a SSD or worse performance wise?

Is there a reason you're tied to hardware RAID over software RAID? It'll almost certainly be easier and cheaper (and likely more performant) to run software RAID.

If you read the linked Broadcom datasheet carefully, it says that there are two NVMe ports with PCIe 3.1 x4, roughly ~3.9 GB/s each. You're still two ports short though.

@Zac67 thank you very much for your comment. where did you extract that information from? From the image on page 2? My apologies if the questions sound dumb, but I am no hardware expert. In page 3 it states that the 16i model can support "Four x4, Eight x2" NVME drives. 8GT/s is approximately the same as 8Gb/s is that it? So a x4 will be able to do 4GT/s? Four x4 means 4 disks at ~500MB/s?

Yes, the diagram on page 2 - it shows only two links, but apparently (text box on left) up to eight are possible. 8 GT/s is nearly 8 Gbit/s (exactly 8*128/130 Gbit/s). "8 GT/s x4" means four lanes in parallel, 8 GT/s each = 32 GT/s aggregated or 3.9 GB/s usable bandwidth. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Comparison_table for PCIe in general.

@Zac67 sorry but this is still not crystal clear to me:

"8 GT/s x4" means four lanes in parallel, 8 GT/s each = 32 GT/s aggregated or 3.9 GB/s usable bandwidth
3.9 usable per disk or shared by all disks? Will each disk have 3.9GB/s or if there are 4 disks, it would be ~1GB/s per disk? If that is the case, it seems the controller would be a significant bottleneck with 4 disks.
Or would it be 3.9 per lane, we have 4 lanes in 1 of the PCI links, and since there are 2, I have 32GT/s in one link and 32GT/s in the other link? 32GT/s shared by 2 disks and 32GT/s shared by 2 other disks?


3.9 GB/s per (8 GT/s x4) port = per disk. The all-over controller throughput is bottlenecked by its host interface (last page) of PCIe 3 x8 = 7.9 GB/s = total for all disks. If that's not enough you need another controller (series). The Highpoint has twice that (with PCIe 3 x16) but I wouldn't recommend that brand.

@Zac67 I don't really like highpoint for servers, I have used it in non production environments, but I agree with you, I would rather go for the broadcom one. I believe I can live with 7.9GB/s for now :)
You have been very helpful, If you want to convert your comments into an answer, I would be glad to mark it as correct.
I would leave a last question for you: You say "3.9 GB/s per (8 GT/s x4) port = per disk". From my understanding of the docs, we can have 2 disks in each x4 port, or am I reading this incorrectly? In fact we would have 2 disks per port, something like 1.95GB/s per disk?

In the linked Broadcom datasheet, you'll find that there are four NVMe ports with PCIe 3.1 x8 = 3.9 GB/s each. It looks like you can split each port for a total of eight ports with PCIe 3.1 x4 = 1.9 GB/s each. I think you can mix x4 and split x2 ports. Since you'll need a suitable backplane between drives and controller, connectivity ultimately depends on that.
The overall Broadcom 9400 controller performance is bottlenecked by its host interface of PCIe 3.1 x8 = 7.9 GB/s. There may be other bottlenecks, the datasheet isn't too specific. For NVMe usage, the SAS and SATA rates don't matter - NVMe uses PCIe for transport. You can find more about achievable PCIe throughput and lane aggregation in Wikipedia.
The Highpoint controller has twice the host-side bandwidth with PCIe 3.0 x16 = 15.8 GB/s total. I wouldn't recommend Highpoint for a production environment though.

Thank you very much for your help :)
